# Limit where C# custom attribute can be used

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm creating an attribute which I only want to be specifiable on interfaces.  Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: Decorate your attribute with [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]

Comment: That's the one, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
 public class MyAttribute : Attribute
 {
 }
```

[You have more options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)